# Why are my html links from django email not clickable?

Tags: python, html, django, email, hyperlink

I sent the following email via Django

```
    subject, from_email, to = 'site Registration', 'support@site.com', self.second_email
    text_content = 'Click on link to finish registration'
    html_content = '<html><body><a href="site.com/accounts/user/' + self.slug +'">Click Here</a></body></html>'
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

When I went the the email (google and yahoo email) they both displayed the Click Here text in blue (I assume this means that it's recognized as a link), however, the link is not clickable and does not link to site.com/acc... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably need to make it a valid URL: *(note the included scheme)*

```
<a href="http://site.com/accounts/user/' + self.slug +'">
```

Answer (score 1):

I built a helper function to do this, and used `render_to_string` to use an HTML template to send instead of typing everything out in the function.  Here's my function:

```
def signup_email(username, email, signup_link):
    subject, from_email, to = 'Site Registration', settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, email
    text_content = 'Click on link to finish registration'
    html_content = render_to_string('pet/html_email.html', {'username': username, 'signup_link':signup_link})
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    return msg
```

Then in the views.py just call it:

```
class OwnerCreateAccount(FormView):
    # class based view  attributes

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # other form logic
        msg = signup_email(username=username, email=email, signup_link=owner.salt)
        msg.send()
        return super(OwnerCreateAccount, self).form_valid(form)
```